# How can I mask sensitive data only for logging in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson-databind

I'm building a Spring Boot application and want to save sign-in request data in db with user password masked. For example, if user passed "abc", I want to save it as "***". I've tried @JsonDeserialize with custom deserializer class. It worked, but the controller also gets a masked password. Although it was a valid password, my service throws error it's wrong password due to masking. Is there any ways to do this?

Here's my code.

```
public class SignInDTO {
    private String id;
    private String pwd;
}
```

```
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/sign-in")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthDTO> signIn(@RequestBody SignInDTO signInDTO) {
        AuthDTO authDTO = authService.getInfo(signInDTO);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(authDTO);
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried.

```
public class SignInDTO {
    private String id;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MaskingSensitiveDataDeserializer.class)
    private String pwd;
}
```

```
public class MaskingSensitiveDataDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        return "****";
    }
}
```

My initial question was how to log masked password, then how about saving it in db? Is there any way to save request body with password masked?

Comment: OBviously a JsonDeserializer isn't the proper way, you need to handle this on your logging side.

Comment: try doing this,
Keep the actual password in your SignInDTO class.

In the controller, mask the password only when you record it in the logs, but pass the actual password to your service.

Make sure you securely manage user passwords within your system, for example by using password hashing and secure storage.

This way, the user password will be recorded in a masked form in the logs, but will be used correctly in your service for authentication.

Comment: Show us how you are doing the logging. There are different ways depending on which logger you are using - [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+mask+sensitive+data+in+logs).

Comment: Re. your edit: Please, please investigate how to save passwords securely. This is not a problem you can figure out by yourself. There are many tools available to you and articles written about how to use them. **Do not, ever, save a plaintext password in your database, or roll your own "obscuring"**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which I used before:

To log the request data with the password masked, you can use a custom logger that intercepts the request and masks the password before logging it. Here's a simplified example using a custom logging filter:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MaskedPasswordLoggingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Wrap the request to intercept the body
        MaskedPasswordLoggingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MaskedPasswordLoggingRequestWrapper(request);
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }
}
```

In the ***MaskedPasswordLoggingFilter***, you can wrap the ***ServletRequest*** with a custom ***HttpServletRequestWrapper*** (e.g., ***MaskedPasswordLoggingRequestWrapper***) that masks the password before logging.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MaskedPasswordLoggingRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public MaskedPasswordLoggingRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        // Replace the original reader with a custom reader that masks the password
        return new MaskedPasswordBufferedReader(super.getReader());
    }
}
```

*A friendly advice:*

If you want to save the masked password in the database, you can do so after intercepting the request using a similar approach. However, it's important to consider security and **hashing the password properly before saving it** to the database. Storing plain passwords, even if masked, is not recommended for security reasons.

It's generally a better practice to store securely hashed passwords in the database and mask them only for logging or display purposes. When a user logs in, you would hash the provided password and compare it with the hashed value stored in the database.

Here's a high-level outline:

- Hash the password using a strong hashing algorithm (e.g., bcrypt) and store the hashed value in the database during user registration or password update.
- When logging requests, use a logging filter or interceptor to mask
  the password for logging or display purposes only.
- When authenticating users, hash the provided password and compare it
  with the hashed value stored in the database.

This approach ensures that passwords are stored securely while allowing you to log or display masked passwords as needed.